# Переклад слова "parent"

Tags: переклад, from-english, відповідник

[Parent](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/parent) - англійське слово, що має значення: "Мати чи батько людини чи тварини".

Потрібно перекласти у такому реченні:

> Was she, in mourning her butchered **parent**, crying out (she had not
>   wept) for a guilty man?

На жаль, з контексту неможливо зрозуміти, про кого саме йдеться - про матір чи про батька.

При пошуку варіантів перекладу даного слова Гугл видав такі результати: "батько", "джерело", "прабатько", "родитель". Жодне з цих слів не підходить, бо всі вони (окрім "джерела") означають лише чоловіка. Словник [Глосб](https://uk.glosbe.com/en/uk/parent) також нічим мені не допоміг.

То чи є в українській мові якесь слово, яким би можна було перекласти англійське "parent"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На ресурсі [r2u.org.ua](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) присутній варіант українською для обох родів **`родитель`** і **`родителька`**.

Зокрема, їх пропонують:

**Словарь української мови 1909р. (Б. Грінченко)**

> **Роди́тель**, -ля, м. Родитель, отець. Чуб. III. 29. Шануй учителя паче родителя. Ном. № 6101. Роди́телі. а) Родители, отецъ и мать. Та я
>   ж буду віконечка одсувать і своїх родителів в гості виглядать. Мил.
>   181. б) Родственники (покойные?) Дочь плачетъ надъ мертвымъ отцомъ. Стрічайте, мої родителі, мого татуся рідненького, пробірайте містечко
>   коло себе близесенько і доглядайте так, як я доглядала. Мил. 189. На
>   проводи в нас на гробки ходять, родителів поминають. Черниг. г.

та

**Словарь росийсько-український 1893–1898рр. (М.Уманець, А.Спілка.)**

> Роди́тель, ница = **роди́тель, ба́тько і д. Отецъ, роди́телька, ма́ти
>   і д. Мать**.

Обидва іменники наявні і в СУМ, хоч і з позначкою "рідко":

> [**РОДИ́ТЕЛЬ**](http://sum.in.ua/s/rodytelj), я, чол., рідко. Те саме, що батько 1. — Та хай
>   тільки заявиться — я шкуру з нього [сина] спущу! Ломакою вам його
>   прижену! Щоб напоумили! Щоб родителя свого шанував! (Олесь Гончар,
>   Партиз. іскра, 1958, 79).
>
> Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 8, 1977. — Стор. 595.
>
> [**РОДИ́ТЕЛЬКА**](http://sum.in.ua/s/rodyteljka), и, жін., рідко. Те саме, що мати1 1. Як
>   закричить же Хведір, як зарепетує! — Ой, пробі, пробі! Ой, клоччя
>   пече!.. Матінко ж моя, родителько, моя ж ти сотворителько!.. Ой,
>   пробі!.. (Гнат Хоткевич, I, 1966, 78).
>
> Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 8, 1977. — Стор. 595.

Аналогічно знаходимо обидва іменники на [Вікі Київського університету імені Бориса Грінченка](http://wiki.kubg.edu.ua/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%A0%D0%BE).

Не так вже й мало результатів дає й Google Search, наприклад, за словом [**`родителька`**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0&oq=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61j0l2.4865j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Що ж до наведеної Вами цитати, то з ширшого контексту все ж зрозуміло, що мова про батька, тому сміливо можна вживати цей чудовий іменник.

[Contemporary Indian Writing in English between Global Fiction and Transmodern Historiography by Christoph Senft](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=AyVzCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA93&lpg=PA93&dq=Was%20she,%20in%20mourning%20her%20butchered%20parent,%20crying%20out%20(she%20had%20not%20wept)%20for%20a%20guilty%20man?&source=bl&ots=HVqAMGbySk&sig=ACfU3U25aTLxWPKp03_fIbv9aMEFjC4Lbw&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjVxKDt5c3gAhUP0aYKHc-ZCtcQ6AEwAnoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=Was%20she%2C%20in%20mourning%20her%20butchered%20parent%2C%20crying%20out%20(she%20had%20not%20wept)%20for%20a%20guilty%20man%3F&f=false)

[image]

[Shalimar the Clown by Salman Rushdie](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=_7l7iqOeO3sC&pg=PA335&lpg=PA335&dq=Was%20she,%20in%20mourning%20her%20butchered%20parent,%20crying%20out%20(she%20had%20not%20wept)%20for%20a%20guilty%20man?&source=bl&ots=QO1bSltMSw&sig=ACfU3U0wqQm7yLm-mgXJnl4VG8NB1NH5mQ&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNwMDd6s3gAhXJwcQBHYuzA6AQ6AEwBHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=Was%20she%2C%20in%20mourning%20her%20butchered%20parent%2C%20crying%20out%20(she%20had%20not%20wept)%20for%20a%20guilty%20man%3F&f=false)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Додам, же згаданий тут [r2u](//r2u.org.ua/s?highlight=on&w=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA) також наводе **рожде́ник**.

*Словник українсько-російський 1927р. (А. Ніковський)*

> **Рожде́ник** – родитель.

Російсько-український словник ділової мови 1930р. (М. Дорошенко, М. Станиславський, В. Страшкевич)

> **Родитель** – ба́тько, рожде́ник (-ка).

Словарь української мови 1909р. (Б. Грінченко)

> **Рожде́ник**, **-ка**, м. Родитель. Рк. Левиц.

Має лише одну перевагу над *родитель*: *-[тель](https://ukrlit.net/info/criticism/staroslovyanizm.html)* — церковнословянський наросток, а *-ник* — словянський. Але, схоже, одразу втрачає перевагу через сполуку *-жд-* замість *-дж-* чи *-ж-*, порівняйте: *[урожденець](https://r2u.org.ua/s?highlight=on&w=%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C)* з *[уродженець](https://r2u.org.ua/s?&highlight=on&w=%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C)* чи *[уроженець](https://google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&q=%22%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C%22)*; *[рождати](https://r2u.org.ua/s?highlight=on&w=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)* з *[роджати](https://r2u.org.ua/s?highlight=on&w=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)*, *[рожати](https://r2u.org.ua/s?highlight=on&w=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)* ітд. Тому на український лад наче мусе бути **ро(д)женик**, але такого ужитку не знаходю.

Comment: Я лише з другого прочитання зрозумів, що *жд* це збіг літер, і то не певен в цьому. А чому через це слова втрачають досі не зрозумів.

Comment: @Yola, я думаю, stegetsj мав на увазі, що в більшості сучасних однокорінних слів маємо -дж-, а тут раптом -жд-, отже схоже на росіянізм або церковнослов'янізм.

Answer (score 0):

[Загальний народний англійсько-український словник 2010–](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=parent&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on)

> parent [ˈpeərənt, амер. ˈperənt ˈpær-]
>     1. n
>       1) ба́тько, ма́ти; заст. породитель, роди́лець
>       2) праба́тько, пра́оте́ць, ***пре́док***
>       3) біол. тварина або рослина, від якої пішли інші
>       4) причи́на; осно́ва; джерело́
>       5) батьківська компанія, організація тощо
>     2. adj
>       1) батькі́вський, матери́нський
>       2) перви́нний, початко́вий, поро́джувальний; вихідни́й
>     3. v
>       бути батьком, матір’ю; виховувати (дітей)

Такий же переклад на цьому [сайті](https://www.yenotes.com/uk/?q=parent&from_lang=en&to_lang=uk)

На мою думку, в наведеному вами речені варто використати слово ["предок"](http://sum.in.ua/s/predok), тобто без означення жінка чи чоловік.

Comment: Предок — це не зовсім те, це ширше значення. Parent — це саме предок першого рівня (батько або мати), а предок — це може бути і дід/бабуся, і прадід/прабабуся, і т.п. (Хоча в деяких випадках, звісно, це не суттєво.)